# How do I compile only the Substrate node-template from the Substrate repo?

Tags: substrate-node-template

How do I compile only the Substrate node-template from the Substrate repo:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node-template

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion is to install [sccache](https://github.com/mozilla/sccache).

Compilation times can be a major bottleneck when building large projects. This tool caches compiled objects, so that they can be reused in future builds, thereby reducing the time taken to compile dependencies.

To install sccache, you can follow the instructions provided in the GitHub repository. The installation process involves installing the tool and its dependencies, and configuring it to work with your build system. Once set up, sccache should work seamlessly in the background, helping to speed up your builds and save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cargo build -r -p node-template
```

Keep in mind you can also use:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template

Which is a CI that takes the node-template from the Substrate repo regularly.